# How to connect via mongoose and a ssh tunnel

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ssh, mongoose

I have setup my mongod.conf as follows so it only allows localhost connection.

```
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true

systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```

I then want my site to ssh into the mongodb so the port has to be converted to localhost.

However how can I integrate this with mongoose's connect function?

```
mongoose.connect(configDB.url, function(err){
  if (err){
    console.log('Error connecting to mongodb: ' + err)
  }
});
```

I have found the following command but I am not sure if this is what I need:

```
ssh -L 4321:localhost:27017 -i ~/.ssh/ssh_key user@ip-adress
```

This should ssh me via port 4321 to the localhost right? So I think I need something like this in the nodejs mongoose's connect function. I've tried to read up on this on the mongodb security tutorials but I cannot link their instructions to nodejs at all. Anyone who has experience with this?

Answer (score 6):

You're nearly there. Set up the tunnel independent of node:

```
ssh -Nf -p [db_server_ssh_port] [mongo_user]@[mongo_domain] -L \
[local_db_port]:localhost:[remote_db_port]
```

And then within node, connect to mongo using [local_db_port]:

```
mongoose.connect(
  "mongodb://localhost:[local_db_port]/[db_name]",
  {"pass":"[db_pwd]"}
)
```

All the traffic sent to [local_db_port] on the web server will be sent through the tunnel to port [remote_db_port] on [mongo_domain]. The following post gives more info. It's connecting to a MySQL database, but the principle is the same.

[Connect to MySQL using SSH Tunneling in node-mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895295/connect-to-mysql-using-ssh-tunneling-in-node-mysql)

Answer (score 2):

Set up the tunnel independent of node:

```
ssh -L [your given port]:localhost:27017 [username of ssh]@[ip address of ssh matchine] -f -N
```

after that you have include your given port for mongo database.
In the nodejs you have to setup for mongoose connection like this

```
'mongodb://localhost:[your given port number]/[database name]'
```

enjoy it

Comment: Awesome! Great answer!