# I can't enable "Public access" config in AWS Aurora cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, connectivity

In the [documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/es/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/aurora-private-public-endpoints/) shows that i should can turn on the "Public Access" in RDS Aurora database but I can't see this setting.

[image: RDS Autora Connectivity]

This is the screenshot of another RDS Instance (Not Aurora)

[image]

Anyone have any idea to fix that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You are using an Aurora Serverless cluster. The publicly accessible option is only available for provisioned (non-serverless) clusters. Per the note at the bottom of the page [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/aurora-private-public-endpoints/)

> **Note:** You can't give an Amazon Aurora Serverless DB cluster a public IP address. You can access an Aurora Serverless DB cluster only
> from within a virtual private cloud (VPC), based on the Amazon VPC
> service. For more information, see Using Amazon Aurora Serverless.

Comment: ¡Thanks!

Yes, I'm using Aurora Serverless.
If somebody else have this Issue like me, I'm using this to connect with SSH tunnel (In my case from a Node JS client: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895295/connect-to-mysql-using-ssh-tunneling-in-node-mysql

Comment: Thanks, is that an outdated answer is the serverless option now available from public internet access, the latest document looks like that.

Answer (score 0):

@mark B  Seems now in 2023 public access is available for RDS Aurora serverless, as per their document

Update:- I tried only in RDS Postgress and was able to deploy in both public mode and private to access only within VPC. Both works.

[image]

Comment: I assume you are looking at Aurora Serverless v2. How about deploying that and testing if you can actually connect to it directly over the Internet?

Comment: Yes its Aurora Serverless v2, Thx

Comment: I tried it in RDS Postgress and was able to deploy in both public mode and private to access only within VPC. I believe it would be the same with Aurora.  Did not try in Aurora as it's not in the free tier :-) Thanks

Comment: Regular RDS is not serverless. This question is specifically about Serverless Aurora, not regular RDS. Serverless nodes have always had the limitation of not having a public IP assigned to them, due to their dynamic nature of being regularly replaced by larger/smaller instances during serverless autoscaling. Testing that it works for regular RDS in no way indicates that it works for Serverless Aurora.